# SQL Alchemy - Flask - Many to One

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

sorry for such a basic question but i cant get it straight.

I have a many to one relationship with Users can have 1 specific role. That should be enough for my purpose.
I created the models als following:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__="users"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(128))
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    role = db.relationship('Role', passive_deletes=True)
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer(),db.ForeignKey("roles.id"))


    def check_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password)

    def get_id(self):
        return self.username

    def get_role(self):
        return self.role

 # Define the Role data-model
class Role(db.Model):
        __tablename__ = 'roles'
        id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
        name = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
```

and afterwards i want to set the Role as following

```
....
    vorname =  request.form["inputVorname"]
    nachname =  request.form["inputNachname"]
    staff_user = User(username = vorname[0:1]+nachname[0:3], password_hash = generate_password_hash("test123"))
    role = Role.query.filter(Role.name == request.form.get('inputRole')).first()
    staff_user.role.append(role)
```

In my head:

From a dropdown list i query the correct role object and then i append the table with the object.

but i receive the following:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

i thought that if i have related models/objects i need to append the table with that object?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Since the User only has one role (it is many to one, many users have one role), role is not a `list` so you don't append to it. You just need to say `User.role = role`.

For example code in the question `staff_user.role = role`.